# Genexus select distinct sobre un SDT

Tags: genexus, genexus15

tengo un **sdt** con datos que en algunos registros están repetidos, y necesito hacer un **distinct** sobre este **sdt**. existe alguna forma de generar otro **sdt** con esta información?.
alguien sabe si es posible hacer esto en las versiones X de genexus?
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: revisa la sig. URL: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?24594,Unique+clause+in+Data+Providers,

Comment: hola. la verdad, es que revise lo que indicas, pero no me deja claro como aplicarlo sobre un sdt. tendras algun otro ejemplo que me puedas indicar?. Agradezco desde ya tu ayuda.

Comment: En si un sdt es una estructura que te permite almacenar diversos elementos de un grupo y posteriormente con un bucle... ya sea Foreach o un For In puedes acceder y dentro del mismo realizar la lógica que requieras... revisa el ejemplo que te muestro... a continuación: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?24593,Unique+clause+in+For+Each+command